# Empty link generated for asynchronous Action in MVC 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

According to [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4), older MVCs supports async actions, if they meet a few signature requirements.

I have the following Action:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> ShowDataAsync()
    {
        await GetData();
        return View();
    }

    private async Task GetData()
    {
        eredmeny = await client.GetData();
        ViewBag.Eredmeny = eredmeny;
        RedirectToAction("ShowData", "Blog");
    }
```

I have the following View code:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Show data",actionName: "ShowData", controllerName: "Blog")
```

The generated link looks like this:

```
<a href="">Show data</a>
```

If I change it to synchronous:

```
    public IActionResult ShowData()
    {
        GetData();
        return View();
    }
```

Then it generates the proper link:

```
<a href="/Blog/ShowData">Show data</a>
```

What should I set to make MVC 6 support async actions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You action's method name is `ShowDataAsync` and your view code needs to reflect that.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Show data",actionName: "ShowDataAsync", controllerName: "Blog")
```

Comment: Yes, the View has to be modified as well. None of the tutorials mentioned that...